# Content Hide without overflow hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have use one div content and i want hide last 3 line content without use overflow hidden.

we can use any other property accept overflow hidden.

if there any solution for that please let me know.

Thank You

Comment: If the lines are inside other elements, like `span`, use `display:none`.

Comment: no my content is dynamic.

Comment: it would helpful if you could post the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the content you want hidden in `span` tags and use `display: none`. In your case, this might look like:

```
<div>
    Visible stuff
    goes here
    <span style="display: none;">
        Last three
        lines of your
        content to hide
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This way dose not help me.